# access assigned display in java for Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: java, macos, swing, osx-mavericks

I have a java swing application that tries to center some dialogs that have no parents on the screen.

Since Mac OS X 10.9, spaces can be separated per display and you can assign an application to a space and thereby also to a display. 
Is there any way I can get that display before opening a new window/dialog?

I tried: 
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
but that returns always the "main" screen, not the one the application is assigned to.

Using the wrong screen to compute the position can lead to dialogs partially (or in extreme cases even fully) out of the screen.

For now I made a workaround and store the screen the application was running on the last time and use that to identify the correct screen. But it would be nice to get a clean way to find the correct screen.